# pip3: command not found but python3-pip is already installed

Tags: python, pip

I can't use pip3 though python3-pip has already been installed. How to solve the problem?

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
sudo: pip3: command not found

sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

Comment: can you try to locate the pip3 in your comp?

Comment: What version of Debian/Ubuntu (or derivatives) are you using?

Comment: This page helps me realise that `pip` or `pip3` is the correct command name rather than `python3-pip`.

Comment: the installation is in your ~/.local/bin/pip3, not in your system path.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Run

```
locate pip3
```

it should give you a list of results like this

```
/<path>/pip3
/<path>/pip3.x
```

go to /usr/local/bin to make a symbolic link to where your pip3 is located

```
ln -s /<path>/pip3.x /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Comment: @MarkZar, If you don't mind, pls accept the Answer thanks =)

Comment: In my case I had same python 3 virtual environments that I was able to delete using the `locate` command and then install `python3-pip`

Comment: ln -s /<path>/pip3 /usr/bin/pip3,    this works for me

Comment: this answer makes more fragile an already suspect system ... a better solution is mentioned below to first remove then install python3-pip

Comment: @Prometheus u may need sudo command in front of the the locate

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. :( I am running it on a VM - CentOS

Comment: @Prometheus u may wanna check under /bin and /usr/bin to see if locate actually exist, u may need to install that command first. alternately, checkout the other solutions below.

Answer (score 175):

You can use `python3 -m pip` as a synonym for `pip3`. That has saved me a couple of times.

Comment: This really works. And you can use sudo with it. If you only make a link, you cannot use sudo unless you are root.

Comment: Just use `python3 -m pip install X` instead of using pip3 install X and it will work like charm. I wanted to use pip3 install pillow but it was not working so used `python3 -m pip install pillow` and it worked.

Answer (score 71):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I had to uninstall and then reinstall pip3:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: also worked for me, but not before doing a few things (reopened console, ran hash -r, tried symbolic linking above, deleted the located pip3 paths - or at least tried to). One of the things I did made this work when it did not before

Comment: seems bad installation of `python3-pip` is a common issue (?). this answer also worked for me too on `Ubuntu 18.04`  (which several months ago was updated from `Ubuntu 16.04`;

Answer (score 3):

You can make symbolic link to you pip3:

```
sudo ln -s $(which pip3) /usr/bin/pip3
```

It helps me in RHEL 7.6

Answer (score 1):

For Kali, you must use this code after the update.

```
$sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

or if you write this, it also works but not supported anymore. So don't use:

```
$sudo python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `pip3` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/` which is not in the PATH of the `sudo` (root) user.
Use this instead

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 install Python from Python.org
Once installed add these two paths to PATH env variable
C:\Users<your user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
C:\Users<your user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts

Open command prompt and following command should be working
python --version
pip --version

Answer (score 0):

This is the generic solution for all type of issues like `Package 'xyz' has no installation candidate` or command not found but  is already installed:

just run this command

`rmadison <package_name>`

eg: `rmadison python3-pip`

The above command will query the apt database.

if you were not able to run the above command: `sudo apt install devscripts` and then run `rmadison` command.

and to query for specific distro use `| grep focal`
-> `rmadison <package_name> | grep focal`

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to install virtualenv. Just create a workfolder and open your editor in it. Assuming you are using vscode,

```
$mkdir Directory && cd Directory
$code .
```

It is the best way to avoid breaking Ubuntu/linux dependencies by messing around with environments. In case anything goes wrong, you can always delete that folder and begin afresh. Otherwise, messing up with the ubuntu/linux python environments could mess up system apps/OS (including the terminal). Then you can press shift+P and type python:select interpreter. Choose any version above 3. After that you can do

```
$pip3 -v
```

It will display the pip version. You can then use it for installations as

```
$pip3 install Library
```