# How to tell installer (pip/pip3) to install all packages under python3.6?

Tags: python, pip

I have two versions of python ( 2.7 and 3.6.4) installed on `ubuntu 16.04`. Now I only want to work on 3.6.

I want to install few packages like `pandas` and `psycopg2`.

I tried to install it with `pip3 install pandas` and it shows successfully installed. However, when I am trying to import from python 3.6 it is throwing me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'.
```

Now the question is how to tell installer (`pip/pip3`) to install all packages under python3.6 so that I can import the installed packages?

Comment: How are you checking by importing? make sure you are checking it in python 3.6

Comment: pip3 install package under python 2, maybe you just not succeed to install it

Comment: yes, i am checking under python3.6 console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run pip of different version of python using python command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803040/how-to-run-pip-of-different-version-of-python-using-python-command)

Answer (score 1):

`python3 -m pip install pandas`

This is [advice](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/968634031842603008) from [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger).

Comment: i got `Requirement already satisfied` whereas when i am trying to import pandas from python3.6 console i am getting same error

Comment: What you can do is to check what's actually version you running, and where pandas was installed. You can try to run `-m pip freeze` with `python3.6`, `python3` and `python` commands (like `python3.6 -m pip freeze`). Maybe you have some extra install?

Comment: not able to locate `pandas` anywhere, i used `whereis pandas` got nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried virtual environments?

[revelant documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Create a python3.6 virtual environment and activate it and work on that

Answer (score 0):

You can install it for python 3.6 using:

```
pip3.6 install pandas
```

But a better way to work with different versions of python would be to use virtual environments. Look into anaconda: https://conda.io/docs/ or virtualenv: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: @TarunK This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993086/pip3-command-not-found-but-python3-pip-is-already-installed. And still I would very strongly suggest to move to conda. :D

Comment: well last week i tried conda but things are still not working, well all i want is to work on python3.6 and need to remove all versions .